# Segmentation fault in C (Trying to make a chess game)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am making chess in C and I am getting a segmentation fault in my bool check (This is supposed to make the program see if a player is in check). I think it has something to do with my S variable but I can't really understand what is going on. If someone could tell me what's causing the segmentation fault that would be great.

Thanks!
Edward

```
bool check(void){

    //printf("ran check\n");
for(int x3 = 0; x3 < 8; x3++)
{
    //printf ("here\n");
    for(int y3 = 0; y3 < 8; y3++)
    {
        switch(board[x3][y3])
        {
            int s = 0;
            case 1:
            printf("pawn");
            usleep(50000);
            if (board[x3 - 1][y3 + 1] == 11 || board[x3 + 1][y3 + 1 ] == 11)
            {
                printf("in check");
                return true;
            }
            case 2:

            printf("rooktest");
            do{
              s = s + 1;
              if (board[x3+s][y3] == 11){
                  printf("Rook in check");

                  return true;
              }
            } while (board[x3+s][y3] == 0 || board[x3+s][y3] == 11);


        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `board[x3 - 1]` for example is no good if `x3 == 0`.

Comment: ... similarly `board[x3+s][y3]` and more so in a `while` loop that increments `s` and terminates on the *content* found.

Comment: Pay attention to compiler warnings: `warning: statement will never be executed [-Wswitch-unreachable]` for `int s = 0;`

Comment: I suggest you use `enum`s for the pieces or status instead of hard coding such as `11`.

Comment: The posted code is near useless. Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Answer (score 1):

Where is your board defined? I assume is a global two-dimensional array defined somewhere outside the function block. I need more context but i can say:

In the first if, in the first iteration of the outside loop, when x3=0, causes access to board[-1],  which is a segmentation fault candidate operation, the same with the last iteration resulting in accessing board[8]. In general, I think you are making risking accesses when the x3 is 0 or 7 and y3 is 0 or 7.

I suggest compiling with -g flag, then run the program with gdb a.out and inspect what values are taking the variables at runtime.

Comment: I don't understand what -g flag is. Could you clarify? I am using ide.cs50 to compile my program.

Comment: The -g flag is an option you provide to the compiler. It enables you to run the program inside gdb debugger. This tool lets you put points where the program stops at runtime and accepts from you some commands like print x3 to see what the value for the variable is. Ideally, you should find the program's variables state before the crash and that way infer what caused it to crash.

Comment: Post the complete code and I’ll run it on my computer and debug my own and see what’s going on and then I can help you = )

Comment: Please format code using Markdown (for example `board[-1]`).